# How do you create a desktop shortcut from a Start menu item in Windows 11?

Tags: shortcuts, windows-11

For example, I want to create a desktop shortcut to PuTTY, but there is no menu option anywhere (including submenus) that I can find to do that.

In this screenshot, I've right-clicked "PuTTY":

[image]

Comment: Why can’t you go to the installation folder and create the shortcut from there? You can use “open file location” to accomplish that

Comment: @Ramhound I would rather not; shortcuts can have more elements than just a path. It could have arguments, for example. Also, Windows has had a paradigm since Windows 7 that you shouldn't be messing around in the Program Files directory (kind of like /bin in Linux) unless you have to. Sometimes that directory requires elevated permissions. Creating a desktop shortcut is an entry-level user task, and an entry-level user shouldn't be going into protected directories just to create shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 -Goto PuTTY Installation Folder
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\  or C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY
Step 2  Find putty.exe
Step 3 Right Click on putty.exe and send to desktop (Create Short Cut )

Comment: I would rather not; shortcuts can have more elements than just a path. It could have arguments, for example. Also, Windows has had a paradigm since Windows 7 that you shouldn't be messing around in the Program Files directory (kind of like /bin in Linux) unless you have to. Sometimes that directory requires elevated permissions. Creating a desktop shortcut is an entry-level user task, and an entry-level user shouldn't be going into protected directories just to create shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way of copying a icon from the Start Menu to the desktop
has not changed:

- Ensure that the application icon is visible in the Start Menu
- Click it and hold
- Drag it to the desktop and release when positioned over the desktop,
  to create the desktop icon
- Once the desktop icon is created, you may drag it to any wanted position,

Comment: I am afraid this does not work anymore. I can not drag an icon from a Start Menu to desktop. A crossed red circle appears when I drag an icon over a desktop or other folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click start menu item, More, Open file location
2. Right-click & hold on app EXE, drag it to Desktop, let go of mouse right-click
3. In the context/pop-menu click 'Create shortcuts here'

[You mentioned in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1715906/how-do-you-create-a-desktop-shortcut-from-a-start-menu-item-in-windows-11/1715959#comment2647121_1715906) you didn't want to 'Open file location'. While I can appreciate your view, its misdirected here. What I mean is only the app developer or Microsoft can fix this in the way you want, so telling us you don't like it doesn't help. I believe this has been an issue since Win8 where Microsoft is hiding older methods like this: meaning start menu right-clicks act differently than File Explorer right-click. So either you request the app developer to program better for newer Windows or you do it via the methods that have been suggested to you. Sadly I don't think you'll convince Microsoft to change their concepts/OS, but I'm happy to be wrong.

Comment: There is no 'More' menu item in the context menu for the Start Menu items on Win 11, instead you see directly the 'Open file location' action. The problem is, it does not appear for Store/Built-in applications.

Comment: The 'More' is seen in the OP's picture, but I am sure you are right that it doesn't appear for Store/Built-in apps. In that case I'd try to click & drag it to the Desktop, it works on Win10, sadly I don't have a Win11 to test with currently

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://www.minitool.com/news/add-microsoft-store-app-to-desktop.html), you can drag & drop a shortcut from the Start Menu to the desktop (or elsewhere) like this:

- Click Start **and click All apps** This will show a list of all apps you have installed in Windows.
- Find the target app from the list, drag and pull the app from the Start menu to the desktop. This will create a desktop shortcut for the app installed from Microsoft Store.

The notable part, as highlighted above, is to click All apps (above the pinned startup items), otherwise you can't drag & drop the program, as noted in the other comments.